# Use a component inside another component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have set the "name" property in Oneway.vue but I can't use the component and I got this error:
did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

```js
import Oneway from '../Flight/Oneway';
export default {
  name:'FlightResult',
  components:{
    Oneway
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
    <div>
        <one-way></one-way>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: if you callled to your component`Oneway` then use it as `<oneway>`, to use it as `<one-way>` his name should be `OneWay`

Comment: I did it, it's shown for first time but when I refresh the page I have the error again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import the component as `OneWay` not `Oneway`

Answer (score 1):

For alternative answer , you can define component name as below

```
import Oneway from '../Flight/Oneway';
export default {
  name:'FlightResult',
  components:{
    'one-way': Oneway
  }
}
```